# Invalid asm.js: Invalid member of stdlib

Tags: solidity

(node:7894) V8: /var/www/html/testeth/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:3 Invalid asm.js: Invalid member of stdlib

i am making the test deploy on ganache-cli simple contract but it is showing that warning. Please help to resolve that problem.

Below the code of the "index.sol"

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract testalk{

string public message;

function testalk(string initialMsg) public {
    message = initialMsg;
}

function setMessage(string nwMsg) public {
    message = nwMsg;
}

}
```

and i am testing it using "mocha" and ganache-cli provider as code below :-

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const { interface, bytecode} = require('../compile');

require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 15;

let accounts;
let testeth;

beforeEach( async ()=>{

accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

testeth = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
                .deploy({data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi Alok!']})
                .send({gas: '1000000',from: accounts['0']});

});

describe("testalk",() => {
it('deploy a contract', () =>{
    assert.ok(testeth.options.address);
});

it('get the message', async () => {
    const message = await testeth.methods.message().call();
    assert.equal('Hi Alok!', message);
    //console.log(message);
})

it('get the message', async () => {
    await testeth.methods.setMessage("Bye Alok!").send({from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000'});

    const message = await testeth.methods.message().call();
    console.log(message);

});

});
```

I am using Ubuntu and nodejs.

Comment: throw some code to let me know better.

Comment: Please add some details, following the post [How can I ask a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145405/how-can-i-ask-a-question-that-can-be-answered-with-a-better-approach). Thank you

Answer (score 2):

npm install solc@0.4.26

This resoloved the issue for me.

Comment: perfect. This worked for me as well. I got this error when I had originally installed: npm install solc@0.4.17

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to select a newer version of the solc compiler (e.g. check Remix to see which version works with your code). Check that the version in the `pragma` sentence of your Solidity code is the same as the solc version you have installed with node. Check the sample usages in the solc releases and copy the JS code. I used 0.7.4 https://libraries.io/npm/solc/0.7.4

After that, you need to adapt the compile script to return the ABI and bytecode to your tests. The names must match exactly. Here I'm returning the values in JSON format so I don't have to use `JSON.parse(interface)` in my test file. Note that the bytecode is only the HEX value, therefore I'm returning the `contract.evm.bytecode.object`. Change Lottery by the name of your contract (if you have multiple contracts you want to check the docs or try a for loop).

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const lotteryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Lottery.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(lotteryPath, 'utf8')

var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
      'test.sol': {
        content: source
      }
    },
    settings: {
      outputSelection: {
        '*': {
          '*': ['*']
        }
      }
    }
  };
  
var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
var contract = output.contracts['test.sol'].Lottery;
var bytecode = contract.evm.bytecode.object;
var interface = contract.abi;
module.exports = {interface, bytecode};
```

My test file didn't change much, but here it is:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const { interface, bytecode } = require('../compile');

let lottery;
let accounts;

beforeEach(async () => {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    lottery = await new web3.eth.Contract(interface)
        .deploy({ data: bytecode })
        .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '6000000' });
});

describe('Lottery Contract', () => {
    it('deploys a contract', () => {
        assert.ok(lottery.options.address);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because of many reasons. If you are using remix ide then by default asm is disabled in chrome that could be an issue. You could be using old compiler of Solidity in some incompatible way. There could be issues with your code itself. Unless you give all specifics of the code, the environment you are using like IDE and Operating System etc., anyone can only guess the max.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install *solc* version >= 0.4.26.
Also, make sure you've correctly installed  **truffle-hdwallet-provider** since it's been renamed to **@truffle/hdwallet-provider**.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the invalid member of stdlib and "before each" hook for "deploys a contract" problems by deleting the "node-modules" folder in the current directory and then reinstall the modules from terminal:

`npm install --save ganache-cli mocha web3@1.0.0-beta.37 solc@0.4.17`

If you have anaconda installed on your computer you should deactivate it before installing these modules by using the 
`conda deactivate` 
command. I couldn't find a solution for this on internet and I hope this helps you to solve your problem as well...